# FM receiver circuit

Tags: frequency-modulation

I am doing a college project where I have to build an FM receiver.

I didn't have a lot of knowledge about the subject before starting my research. Now, I understand the function of the principal components of the circuit.

[image]

The problem is that, when I try to go deeper and look for precise circuits, I don't understand how the different parts interact with each other and I cannot identify the principal components in such plans.

[image]

I can't tell exactly what happens with the electric power when it passes in that circuit and I don't know where are the filters, the oscillator, the mixer and the demodulator.

Comment: Please provide references for the images

Comment: hi! What's the course you're doing this for? Because you have a few misconceptions, you're mixing up an *exemplary implementation of one type of receiver* with the *logical block diagram of a completely different receiver*, and you seem to be using sources of information that aren't typical in quality for a college with a library; so I wonder at what point we should be starting to help you.

Comment: Please also try to be exact about what your project is. Is it "*build any one FM receiver, no matter which type, as long as it works?*" Or is it "*demonstrate and explain the functionality of a superheterodyne receiver*"? Or is it something else? Also, as Voltage Spike very correctly points out, you're not giving any sources for your images and it would be **really important** to understand why you consider these two figures to be relevant to your question!

Comment: That circuit is for AM detection (though a nearby over-modulated FM signal might produce *some* audio out). AM of ~100 MHz, to which your circuit might tune,  is used in the Airband, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airband .

Comment: So, please **greatly amend your question**. As it's currently written, it's just a confused mishmash of unrelated figures, things that have nothing to do with FM reception and the statement that you have a project you're not qualified for. That's not a point from which we can honestly start to help you.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time that I am asking a question here, but I understand that it was really unclear/incoherent and I apologize about that.

Comment: To summarize my school project, it is a teamwork where we had to choose the subject we wanted to work on. We decided to create a fm receptor, so our precise objective is to make researches to understand ''how does it works'' and then to assemble a functionnal one. It would be true to say that we aren't really qualified for this project. In class, we only learned basics informations about electronic circuits.

Comment: We had to search online to get the most of our actuel knowledge (electric impedance, LC circuits, superheterodyne components). We were looking for a full plan of an fm receptor and we found that one that seemed reliable to us (the source said it was fm and not am). I now understand that it wasn't good at all, but in facts, what I wanted to know was: '' how does an fm receptor circuit works '', because I've learned the general functionning of the components, but I have difficulty to identify them in a full circuit and to understand exactly all the interactions that occur in the system.

Comment: so, please **edit** your question to include that information.

Comment: also, not every FM receiver is a superheterodyne receiver (as the top image shows a superheterodyne receiver, and the lower does not), and the superheterodyne receiver you showed is not an FM receiver, either, as not every superherheterodyne receiver is an FM receiver, either.

Answer (score 2):

That circuit is nothing like the block diagram, you can't find some of the parts because they're not there.

T1 is an RF amplifier.
T2 is probably the demodulator
The IC is the audio amplifier.

This circuit is designed to use as few components as possible, it's a tuned RF receiver meaning it uses a simple tuned circuit for selectivity and the detector is probably some form of slope detector. The block diagram on the other hand is for a superheterodyne receiver which mixes the signal down to a fixed IF frequency and then does most of the amplification and selectivity at that frequency. The demodulator in one of those would usually be a ratio detector, discriminator, or quadrature detector.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown an a.m. radio detector that’s quite primitive.

T1 resonates and amplifies along with T2 too with some distortion that produces some audio byproduct from T2. Then a class AB amp. IC drives a speaker.

Start with searching for schematics if 60 yr old 6 transistor FM Japanese radios using many of these key words and then look for analysis or performance papers on FM radios to learn what/how they work.

You will unlikely be able to build these as the parts are custom and obsolete. You can however learn a lot from tear-downs and performance comparisons on all the different quality parameters of selectivity, LO fading with AFC, squelch, IM distortion, CNR to SNR, standby power. Then migrate to modern car FM radio designs and SDR designs for cost effectiveness. Building efforts may be futile but also useful for stray effects of coils, which is why shielded coils were used.